# R-replacing multiple column values in selected rows based on another df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame (called master) where each row in the df represents a person ID in a specific year. Meaning one person may have multiple rows for all the years they are present in the data.

Some rows in master have several cells that are missing information in specific columns. So I have collected the missing data for those cells and now the correct data exists in a separate data frame (called df_replace).

I now need to specifically enter the data from the df_replace into the master for those specific IDs in those specific years that are present in df_replace.

My code is currently:
master[master$id %in% df_replace$id,] <- df_replace

But this doesn't work because this doesn't account for the fact that in master, one mID can have multiple rows for each year present in the data. So I need to update this code to account for the "year" column to ensure that the df_replace data is going into the specific row with a specific year and ID. Can anyone tell me how to update this code to do that? I really want to work with a very simple line of code that does not require me to list all the columns in the master that will be updated with data from df_replace because there are dozens of columns in df_replace.

Thank you!
--Medjy

Below is an abbreviated version of my two data frames so you can see how these data frames are structured.

master file:

| id | year | race | gender | age | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2017 | W | F | 17 | 11 |
| 100 | 2018 | NA | NA | 18 | 12 |
| 115 | 2020 | B | M | 15 | 09 |
| 115 | 2021 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

df_replace:

| id | year | race | gender | age | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2017 | W | F | 17 | 11 |
| 100 | 2018 | W | F | 18 | 12 |
| 115 | 2020 | B | M | 15 | 09 |
| 115 | 2021 | B | M | 16 | 10 |

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample data for both `master` and `df_replace`?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for `dplyr::rows_upsert()`, which replaces missing values in table x with matching values from table y, based on key column(s) you specify.

Comment: Sure! I've added the sample data requested. Could you show me how to use the rows_upsert() code in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a merge/join solution. Once it joins on id/year, it iterates over all other columns and "coalesces" (uses first non-`NA` value) the data.

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(master, df_replace, by = c("id", "year"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(
    across(ends_with(".y"),
           ~ coalesce(., pick(sub(".y$", "", cur_column()))[[1]]),
           .names = '{sub(".y$", "", .col)}')
  ) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"))
#    id year race gender age grade
# 1 100 2017    W      F  17    11
# 2 100 2018    W      F  18    12
# 3 115 2020    B      M  15     9
# 4 115 2021    B      M  16    10
```

Digesting that:

- `left_join` normally aligns data based on the `by=` fields; it usually appends `.x` (LHS) and `.y` (RHS) to the joined columns to unambiguous identify from which side a column came, we override this to preserve the first arg as the original without `".x"` appended
- `across` helps us to iterate over selected column, in this case those that end in `.y`
- `coalesce` preserves the first non-`NA` value in each row of the paired columns; the `.` refers to one `*.y` column (RHS on the join), and the `pick(...)` is to get the corresponding column; for instance, if in one iteration we're looking at the `gender.y`, the `pick(.)[[1]]` will retrieve `gender`, effectively making the whole expression `coalesce(gender.y, gender)`, and for each element (row) of the columns, it returns the first non-`NA` value
- `.names=` assigns the value back into the original names (not ending in `.y`)